# Why capitalize React here? import * as React from 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Most examples I see of importing modules use lowercase; e.g.

`import * as tools from './tools';`

The rule I usually see is, if it's a constructor function then use `PascalCase`; otherwise use `camelCase`.

However I always see `import * as React from 'react'` even though React is not a constructor function (can't do `new React()`).  Why is it always capitalized, and when from a JavaScript style standpoint would I choose to capitalize a library or module like './tools'?

Most of my background is in C# and C++ so I'm inclined to capitalize libraries (`import DateFns from 'date-fns'`, `import * as Tools from './Tools'`).

Comment: Not sure whether it helps or not but from the TypeScript definition file `@types/react/index.d.ts`, `React` is a `namespace`.

Comment: There just ins't a rule or even consensus around this. `React` uses uppercase, `angular` uses lowercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is a namespace and I guess because it is a framework brand. Brands that are frameworks tend to get capitalized more often (Vue, Backbone, Ember, etc).

When using Typescript as your javascript super-set it makes a whole lot of sense to capitalize your namespaces, since it has a C# like flavor to it.

But even with new ECMAScript versions there is a benefit to capitalize namespaces. I think it keeps things more readable.

Comment: I think "namespaces" makes sense, and I can see what you mean with brands.  If we have a Tools modules then that is essentially a collection of miscellaneous methods and acts similarly to a namespace, it seems capitalization would not be bad or non-idiomatic JS style.

Comment: That's basically correct. At Facebook module imports are capitalized if the exported value is an object or constructor. Modules that export only a "normal" function are all lowercase.

Comment: @FelixKling How about when exporting a collection of functions or values?

Comment: @LukeWilliams: those would exported as properties of an object.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok.  So if I understand you correctly: in the case of a potpourri of exports, you use something like `default export {method1, method2, method3}` which is then imported with `import MyMethodObject from './MyMethodObject', rather than `export method1; export method2; export method3;` and imported with `import * as MyMethodObject from './MyMethodObject`.

Comment: The only disadvantage I see there is that looking through the module, it's not immediately clear which items are exported and which are not, since all the exporting happens in a single line.

Comment: Or rather, if every function is exported and then at the end a default export is created: all the functions have to be included in both or there will be an inconsistency.  Seems like it would be nice to just have all exports in the file feed into a default export automatically to avoid the repetition and chance for error.

Comment: @LukeWilliams: we haven’t switched to es6 module syntax yet. We are still using commonjs module syntax, i.e. `module.exports = {...}`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah I see.  Thanks so much for the helpful info!

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this older question.

The primary reason why the `'react'` module needs to be imported as `React` (exact spelling and capitalization) is so that JSX works properly.

From the [JSX In Depth doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html):

> Fundamentally, JSX just provides syntactic sugar for the `React.createElement(component, props, ...children)` function.

...and later:

> **React Must Be in Scope**
>
> Since JSX compiles into calls to `React.createElement`, the `React` library must also always be in scope from your JSX code.

---

**Example**

This component in JSX:

```
const SimpleComponent = () => (<div>simple component</div>);
```

...gets compiled into this:

```
var SimpleComponent = function SimpleComponent() {
  return React.createElement("div", null, "simple component");
};
```

...so `React` must exist in the scope or the compiled code will throw this error when it runs:

> ReferenceError: React is not defined